# Classical editing/answer view improvement

Tags: feature-request

**Info :**  It's about the requesting a parallel formatted viewing while editing/answering.

I don't know about most guys but i sometime find it hard to write some little long answers when the length get's longer then i have to scroll down to see full format view plus if some rectification is needed then i have to scroll up-down in the small edit area of the content?

[image]

as in the image if i found something wrong at bottom in view then i have to scroll to bottom inside the edit section which seems like a little small area to me while writing little long posts.

So it would be great if there would be an option to switch from classical view to a parallel viewing where edit are will get more screen size and viewing area will get placed at right side something like in the below image.

It would be great if i can have option like this

[image]

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree with this proposal, but you do realize you can extend the textarea at the bottom, right?

Comment: @Makoto i don't know let me read and try the linked posted , thanks to both

Comment: @Mokoto it's not what i want , i want something like in the 2nd image which will be lot more helpful , this is not what i desired

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan the linked post don't have any answer so can you do anything else for solution ?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan don't you think closing this question will stop helping me to reach the actual guy( if you are not from SO developer group ) who can do something about this ? so it would be helpful to SO if you cast your vote to reopen this post

Comment: To the further reader i didn't find any solution to linked question so i would be great if some of you can vote to reopen this post or you can think 100 other reasons to leave as it is but still would be great if you reopen this

Comment: @PavneetSingh No, closing this question won't stop the people who can help you from knowing about your feature-request, since the feature request has already been made. You can vote for the previous feature-request, which will increase the likelihood of it getting implemented.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan by this  "You can vote for the previous feature-request" you mean up-vote on the duplicate  question ? if yes then i already did it

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan i thought close is like SO down-voting once you get one or no-upvote others mostly don't care unless some reputed guy come at front and do something

Comment: @PavneetSingh I'm not sure what you're saying. Closing as a duplicate keeps your question around; it just points people to the other question. That way, if people want to implement your feature request and find it while searching, they see the dupe and upvote that, so that the votes are concentrated on one request, not spread over two. Closing and downvoting are two separate things. Might want to take a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan i get what you mean but many user don't pay attention when they see closed or duplicate question , anyway  it's done , but i hope i will be notified or something if official SO gonna do anything about it

Comment: If you click the star under the other question, it should notify you of any changes to the question, including when SO updates the tags to include "status-review" or "status-completed" or whatever.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan thanks dude , i know you must be feeling a little pain by now answering again and again to same guy, thanks for the kindness and quick responses , humanity still lives :P